# I want to Move some Mysql table to InnoDB but i don't know what is the best my.cnf conf

Tags: mysql, linux, php

This is my server specification

`my.cnf`:

```
[mysqld]

innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=50000
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
myisam_sort_buffer_size=256M
table_open_cache = 600
thread_cache_size = 4
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_limit = 256K
query_cache_min_res_unit = 2k
query_cache_size = 80M


join_buffer_size = 256k
tmp_table_size = 20M
max_connections = 600

slow-query-log = 1
slow-query-log-file = /output/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
datadir=/disk3/mysql
```

Server Ram

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           62G        61G       1.5G       1.8G       2.0G        53G
-/+ buffers/cache:       5.6G        57G
Swap:         1.9G       230M       1.7G
```

CPU

```
model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 0 @ 2.00GHz × 2
cpu MHz         : 2000.022
cache size      : 15360 KB
```

I have a very big MyIsam Table , each user has status record in it, I select insert join to it. Here is the table :

```
CREATE TABLE `status_userid` (
             `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             `md5id` char(32) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
             `ptype` char(1) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
             `media_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
             `media_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
             `media_photo` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
             `user_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
             `user_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
             `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
             `reason` text COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci,
             PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
             KEY `md5id_mediaid` (`md5id`,`media_id`),
             KEY `user_id_md5id` (`user_id`,`md5id`)
            ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci
```

from `mysql.slow.log`:

```
Count: 1165  Time=11.17s (13008s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=548.3 (638790), myinstar_ranker[myinstar_ranker]@localhost
  SELECT
  s1.id as order_by,
  s1.media_id,
  s1.media_photo,
  s1.user_id,
  s1.user_name,
  s1.date
  FROM `status_427` s1
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT md5id, user_id, ptype FROM `status_427`  WHERE md5id = 'S') s2
  ON
  s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND s2.ptype = 'S'
  WHERE
  s1.md5id = 'S'
  AND s2.md5id IS NULL
  AND s1.date  < NOW() - INTERVAL N DAY
  AND s1.ptype = 'S'
```

---

```
Count: 2247  Time=8.09s (18172s)  Lock=0.00s (1s)  Rows=1.0 (2247), myinstar_ranker[myinstar_ranker]@localhost
  SELECT
  count(N) as counter
  FROM `status_421` s1
  LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT md5id, user_id, ptype FROM `status_421`  WHERE md5id = 'S') s2
  ON
  s1.user_id = s2.user_id AND s2.ptype = 'S'
  WHERE
  s1.md5id = 'S'
  AND s2.md5id IS NULL
  AND s1.date  < NOW() - INTERVAL N DAY
  AND s1.ptype = 'S'
```

I manage to create separate table for each user so I don't end with a huge table if it damaged I lost everything. but this table is very big one, 8M record and counting, that's is why I decided to split it.

Mysql directory on `SSD drive`.

I have a huge mysql using, and the server top is:

```
Tasks: 781 total,   5 running, 775 sleeping,   1 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 41.1%us, 10.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 48.5%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.2%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  65784692k total, 64190512k used,  1594180k free,  2141220k buffers
Swap:  1999868k total,   236436k used,  1763432k free, 56162120k cached

    PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 459105 mysql     20   0 12.4g 286m 6588 S 564.2  0.4 137:35.08 mysqld
```

So, does innoDb may help to reduce mysql Load?
What is the best inndoDb `my.cnf` setting, I was told innoDb is very sensitive and can be damaged so fast, and even more it create a huge log file.

I am not Mysql expert, I know php and some of mysql, but not expert in tuning it.

What are the best setting I can use to reduce server load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is the most important setting for InnoDB.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory
- Tips on converting from MyISAM:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb
- Don't use utf8 for ascii strings.  `md5id`?
- Change `user_id_md5id` to `INDEX(user_id, md5id, ptype)` for the `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )`.
- `INDEX(md5id, ptype, date)`, with date last, for the outer query.
- Rethink having lots of tables named `status_nnn`; there may be better ways to design the schema.
- `max_connections = 600` and `5 running, 775 sleeping` -- It may be better to throttle the number of clients, and not let so many get to MySQL.
- How big is the table?  (rows or GB)

Comment: Dear Rick,Than k you for your reply.
>Don't use utf8 for ascii strings.  md5id?
I dont get this , you mean use asci here ? in the MD5ID ?

i have now  a big problem how can i go to all table and change the indexs ! i have 1450 users then 1450 table .
How big is the table? (rows or GB) , i have 7M row and counting !

max_connections = 600 and 5 running, 775 sleeping -- It may be better to throttle the number of clients, and not let so many get to MySQL.

Well i have 150 client "worker" is doing job but this number gos up and down

Comment: `MD5()` generates hex, which involves 1-byte ascii characters.  utf8 characters take up to 3 bytes.  There is more than one table like this?  One table per user is "bad schema design".  How can there be more sleeping than max_connections??

Comment: thank you so much , regarding this big table , i know that the split is a bad idea but i got this from word press community ,they make tables set for each user , i will go back to one table but i need to make it right , cos i will get all data form all other split table to this table so it is one job to be don and i want to do it one time. alter table is not an easy thing to do each time. regarding sleep , i just show the first line of top, here is full output http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IILQA , Please what to do with my.cnf since i will change to inoDB , PS: can i contact your email!

Comment: i installed mytop , i note a lot of sleep mysql and some sql statement which is i think related to gearmand workers since i have 150 worker waiting the command to be sent via mysql. dos sleep cause a huge load ?
but on other hand , worker will not start mysql connection unless it start the job , while worker in sleep mode thare is no sql connection , but i have other script in loop checking mysql table each 5 sec and sleep 5 sec , here is the sql :http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IILQG

mytop : http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0IILQF

Comment: after research , i found why there is a sleep in mysql , as i told you i have workers waiting for job , when this job passed , worker start using mysql to get the job , then do other works , and use mysql within this works . and die . thats why i have a lot of sleep . now my target is to make this big table work smooth . as i told you i need the correct setting of innodb , I dont like the way "I font this seeting is it good" , i am sure each case has its own settings but i dont know how to reach this since i am php programmer not mysql administrator , thats why i am looking for your help

Comment: @user1402259 - Oh.  WP.  Contact: mysql at rjweb dot org.  WP tip:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta .  If `PROCESSLIST` says `Sleep`, the connection is live, but there is no SQL running _at the moment_.

Comment: On clip/0IILQG, my head spins with both LEFT JOIN and RIGHT JOIN.  `INDEX(connected, checkpoint, activity_status)` may help.

Comment: For the mytop, let's see the entire `SELECT` -- it can probably be improved by not "hiding `date` in a function".  All of the processes show 0 Sleep -- were some others larger than that?  `0` means that they did something very recently.

Comment: How big is `gearman_queue`?  The JOIN with unique_key may be an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59725/discussion-between-user1402259-and-rick-james).